# Angular application does not open in mozilla, getting exited on signal 11 (core dumped) error in logs

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an application which does not open in Mozilla whereas works fine on Chrome. After checking the logs I find that I get this error
exited on signal 11 (core dumped). Any idea as to what it might be related to.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/67504/what-can-cause-a-signal-11)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by mentioning 1.20.0 version of nginx in my docker file.
FROM nginx:1.20.0.
Root cause is that nginx was segfaulting, switching to this version of nginx resolved the issue. Thanks!.